# Python 3.2 SSLError

Tags: python, ssl, instagram-api

I am working on a simple script that calls Instagram API.

Error -

`File "C:\Python32\lib\ssl.py", line 168, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)`
`File "C:\Python32\lib\ssl.py", line 255, in __init__
    raise x`
    `File "C:\Python32\lib\ssl.py", line 251, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()`
`File "C:\Python32\lib\ssl.py", line 430, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()`
`ssl.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:392: EOF occurred in violation of protocol`

Comment: The server closed the connection inside the TLS handshake. Either something with your script is wrong or with the server. Hard to tell without having access to any of these. See also  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that one could actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Here is my code -

Comment: `import ssl`    
`import socket`    

`from instagram.client import InstagramAPI`
`insta_api = InstagramAPI(client_id="<my client id>",
                    client_secret="<my client secret>")`

`recent_media, next_url = insta_api.user_recent_media(user_id="<username>", count=1)`
`for media in recent_media:`
   `print (len(media))`

Comment: Please add the code nicely formatted to the question and don't dump it into a comment.

Comment: It could also be that you are using an 4 year old version of Python which still tries to connect with SSL 3.0 the the server. Could you retry with a current version?

Comment: Sure, thanks @SteffenUllrich